#  prototypes cells  uitableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

hi i try tu use 4 prototypes cells with the storyboard . for each prototypes cells i have a class uitableviewCell with my labels.

look my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier  = @"ProfilCell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"ProfilCell1";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"ProfilCell2";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier3 = @"ProfilCell3";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier4 = @"ProfilCell4";

    if(indexPath.section == 0) 
    {
        ProfilCell* cell =(ProfilCell*)  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.pseudoLabel.text=[[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"pseudo"];

        return cell;

    }

      if(indexPath.section == 1) 
      {
        ProfilCell2* cell = (ProfilCell2*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

       cell.textLabel.text= [[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"status"];

        return cell;

    }

   if(indexPath.section == 2) 
    {
        switch (indexPath.row) 
        {
            case 0:
            {

                 ProfilCell3* cell =(ProfilCell3*)  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
                 cell.ageLabel.text=  [[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"age"];
              return cell;
            }
                break;

            case 1:

            {

                ProfilCell4* cell = (ProfilCell4*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier3];
                cell.deptLabel.text= [[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"localite"];

                return cell;

            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                ProfilCell5* cell = (ProfilCell5*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier4];


                cell.membreLab.text= [[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"membre"];

                return cell;

            }
                break;   
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
          return nil;
}
```

In section 0 section 1  , i have datas in my label but in section 2 case 0 i have this:

```
[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

why my array appears to be empty

it's ok now just give 0 for the indexPath because i have just 1 object in the array!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try something like this...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProfilCell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"ProfilCell1";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"ProfilCell2";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier3 = @"ProfilCell3";

    id cell = nil;

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
              cell = (ProfilCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
              cell.pseudoLabel.text= [[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"pseudo"];
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 1) {
            cell = (ProfilCell2*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
            cell.statusLabel.text= [[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"status"];
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 2) {
            cell =(ProfilCell3*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
            cell.ageLabel.text= [[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"age"];
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 3) {
            cell = (ProfilCell4*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier3];
            cell.deptLabel.text= [[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"localite"];
    }


    return cell;

    }
```

What I've done here is set a var for cell of type `id`, meaning it can be anything. In your if statements you decide what cell is, and set it up accordingly. Only returning 1 instance of cell in the end, and not in each statement. Hope this helps

Comment: If no 'if' statement is taken 'return cell' will return nil - how is this different from his original code posting?

Comment: How do you know if theres not a hardcoded amount of rows, and will never be more or less?..

Answer (score 1):

You should confirm that each of your calls to dequeueReusable... is actually returning a cell.  Use:

```
NSAssert (cell, @"Missed Cell");
```

in the body of each of your 'if' statements.  My suspicion is that a nil cell is being returned.  This would be because your reuse identifier of "ProfilCell", "ProfilCell1", ... does not agree with the cell identifier in the storyboard.  To fix it, go to the storyboard, select each prototype cell one-by-one, confirm that the 'identifier' agrees with what is in your code.  If not, change it to agree.

The 'identifier' must match; not the 'label'!

Answer (score 0):

Check that ProfilCell, ProfilCell2, ProfilCell3 and ProfilCell4 are all subclasses of UITableViewCell

Also check that your cell identifiers match those in the storyboard.

Answer (score -2):

After calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` you **must** check the returned value for `nil`.  If the returned value is not `nil`, then you are fine; you got a reusable cell from the queue.  **But if the returned value is `nil`**, then there were no reusable cells available in the queue.  (This is invariably the case with a newly created table.)  In this latter case, you have to make a new cell, either programatically using `alloc` and `init`:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"] autorelease];
```

or by loading it from a .xib file:

```
cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell"
                                      owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
```

In your case, you might try something like the following (repeat for the other sections):

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    ProfilCell *cell = (ProfilCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)  // if we did not get a reusable cell from the queue, we make one…
    {
        cell = [[ProfilCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.pseudoLabel.text= [[infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"pseudo"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: hi I had used your method but it also crash with this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: When using a storyboard with a prototype cell, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier always returns a valid cell.  There is no need to alloc/init one explicitly.

Comment: Isn't this a quite different error message from the one you got before?  This would suggest that you fixed the earlier problem but have moved on to a new bug.

Comment: Who's the "you" in "you're right"?  Also, why are you sending the setTableViewStyle: method/message to an instance of NSIndexPath?

Comment: And what happened to the earlier error message: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'?  What did you do that made _that_ error message go away?